# Duplicates with ManyToMany

Tags: python, django

I have model:

```
class GPD(models.Model):
    employee  = models.ForeignKey(Employee, verbose_name='Employee', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    gpd_year = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=2021, validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(2121),
            MinValueValidator(2021)
        ])
    corp_goal = models.ManyToManyField(CorporateGoal, blank=True)
    team_goal = models.ManyToManyField(TeamGoal, blank=True)
    ind_goal = models.ManyToManyField(IndividualGoal, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
        print('**********************')
        print(self.corp_goal.all())
        print('**********************')

        return 'GPD ' + str(self.gpd_year) + ' for ' + self.employee.name + ' ' + self.employee.lastname
```

As you can see, I have many to many relationship and when I am trying to `print(self.corp_goal.all())` I have duplicates:
[image]

When I am using `print(self.corp_goal.all().distinct())` - I have the same problem. How fix it?

Comment: These do not look like duplicates: one is `Volume`, the other `Networking Capital`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine. I don't see duplicate, they are two different objects (`Volume` and `Network capital`). You just called it twice.

Comment: But I am printing it once: print(self.corp_goal.all()). In DB everything is ok, I have only 2 different items

Comment: It is because you `print` it for every object. Add third, it will print 3 times. That's why `__str__` method is not a place to print all.